# Python - using list() and manipulating lists

Tags: python, list

I seem to have a problem with my list generating script. I'm trying to convert a string into a list of string-lists,   in order to use it in a specific fonction.

For exemple I want to convert the string 
`'abc'` to a : `[['a'],['b'],['c']]`.
so the script i wrote was:

```
s='some string'
t=[[0]]*len(s)
for i in range(len(s)):
    t[i][0] = list(s)[i]
return t
```

the problem is that this returns `[['g'],['g'],..,['g']]` instead of `[['s'],['o'],..,['g'])`.

I found another way to achieve that, but i can't seem to find the problem of this script.
So,if anyone could help me, i would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see, thank you guys :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic mistake: `[[0]]*n` creates a list of `n` references to a unique object `[0]`. Use this instead to create a list of `n` different objects all equal to `[0]`: `[[0] for i in range(n)]`. This way, you can then change the value of each of them without affecting the others.

Answer (score 5):

`[[0]] * len(s)` doesn't do what you think it does, consider this better approach:

```
s = 'abc'
li = [[ch] for ch in s]
print(li)
>> [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
```

Comment: You can add a condition in your comprehension to ignore whitespace too in order to just have all non-whitespace characters. But I guess it also depends on what characters are expected to be kept in the list.